# Html text position is not at the same place when I shrink my window size

Tags: html, css

When I shrink the window of my browser,the text gather together and it is all messed up.
Is there any code I can use to prevent this happens?I want them to stay in their own position no matter what size the window is.

```css
.fixedmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:rgb(153,0,51);
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    font-size:2em;
    left:0;
    position:relative;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;    
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedmenu">

<div style="float: left;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 3%;">
    || YggDrasil ||
</div>

<div style="float: right;color:white;padding:0.5% 3% 0.5% 0%;">
    || Login ||
</div>

<div style="margin:0 auto; width:30%;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;">
    Welcome to the page of leading to fashion. 
</div>

</div>
```

[I don't want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ul1Z.png)

Comment: Could you add some HTML as well to show the issue?

Comment: Just posted on my question, thanks

Comment: May be its font size that is creating issue. Try with some px.

Comment: just add a width to your fixed menu - it gets messed up as your fixed menu will resize, if you want it to stay in a fixed position, give the container a fixed width

Comment: @ShangHuang you need to add your HTML as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53633474/edit) to your question, not as a new answer.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the edit button just now, still new to this. Deleted the answer. Thanks

Comment: It is not about the font size, I try every method that I know but it is not working..

Comment: The container for your text has a width of 30% which is why it only takes up 30% of the screen. You could add `min-width: 1000px` to prevent it shrinking beyond a certain point.

Comment: @Pete I put max and min width to it , still not working..

Comment: you need a fixed width - just a width not one that will allow changes to it's size - it's the changing size that is causing your issue

Comment: @M̨̹̖̱̠̭̠̱̘͌̓ͬͫa̧͔͇̗͖͖͑ͭ͝t̆͗̊ͫt But this will cause my container not floating on the middle as the container goes bigger size.

Comment: @Pete How to do a fixed width? What I found on web was told to set max and min  width to fix it.

Comment: `width:1000px`?

Comment: @ShangHuang also add `text-align: center` to fix this

Comment: @Pete `width: 1000px` is an example, you can choose whatever size you like.

Comment: sorry @M̨̹̖̱̠̭̠̱̘͌̓ͬͫa̧͔͇̗͖͖͑ͭ͝t̆͗̊ͫt I was showing shang how to add a width

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```css
.fixedmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:rgb(153,0,51);
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    font-size:2em;
    left:0;
    position:relative;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;    
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedmenu">

<div style="float: left;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 3%;">
    || YggDrasil ||
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;right:0px;color:white;padding:0.5% 3% 0.5% 0%;">
    || Login ||
</div>

<div style="margin:0 auto; width:30%;color:white;padding:0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;">
    Welcome to the page of leading to fashion. 
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Describe what changes you are making and why this is an answer.

Comment: i changed login to position:absolute; right:0px; hope this help

Comment: hahaha, spent a good 3 minutes trying to figure out what the difference in this answer was then and couldn't see anything - code only answers are never good and will most likely get you downvoted as it doesn't explain anything and just becomes a game of spot the difference

Comment: Pete it wasnt responsive

Comment: Yeah OP has not explained very well what they are after, but I don't see how this is any better than what they have - if you hit run on the snippet, it looks exactly like the image of what OP says they don't want and with absolute positioning, you will get the right text overlapping the other at certain points so if anything it would have made it worse, but hey ho, if the OP says it's fixed their solution then fair play

Comment: yeah because before answering i tried it on mobile size

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent shrinking in this case is to give a fixed size to `.fixedMenu` (not in percentage). In general, any rule given in percentages is subject to shrink if the parent element resizes, like the paddings and the width of 30% that you have set in the inline styles. And one last thing, you are setting the `position` property twice, resulting in an override. The quickest fix would be:

```
.fixedmenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:rgb(153,0,51);
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 1200px; 
    font-size:2em;
    left:0;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;    
}
```

But the best way in my opinion would be to set some media queries in order to better address the changing size of the window.

Comment: I was told to not use px to set the width instead of % is because to prevent when the other pc have different resolution so it will not fit..

Comment: For an example, I am now putting 2000px for my pc but when I open the website in my laptop which has a smaller screen, it won't fit and the text "login" will overlay.

Comment: Ok then [godfather](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9303969/godfather)'s answer might work. Maybe in order to have a better control you should move the inline styles in new rules outside of the html, and maybe increase the 30% percentage of the main div for smaller screens with a media query.